# running android emulator in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-emulator

Does anyone know how to run the emulator within eclipse without using ADT. All I want to do is run the emulator with -partition-size  option of the emulator and you cant do this by default. Im sure there might be a tricky way of doing this but googling doesn't give me any clues. does any one know ?

I also thought about running the emulator as part of a script and call the script within eclipse.

running on a mac bdw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh found it.

Eclipse has "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" in Run configuration under the tab "Target".

This seems to be hidden on my eclipse which might be an eclipse bug. should've been a scrollbar or something.

anyways you can add any emulator options there which seems work well.